# AttributeError resulting from function defined in class definition

Tags: python, function, class, attributes

I am trying to learn how to define classes in Python, starting by creating a very basic example:

```
class CustomClass:
    def print_class(self):
        print(self)

CustomClass = 'Hello World'
CustomClass.print_class()
```

Yet when I run this, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'print_class'
```

I don't want to try to access or define some attribute of this class. I want to run the function defined when the class is defined. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You *redefined* the `CustomClass` reference to a string `'HelloWorld'`.

Comment: remove `CustomClass = 'Hello World'` and it will work.

Comment: What do you think `CustomClass = 'Hello World'` does?

Answer (score 2):

what do you wanted to do with this statement: **CustomClass = 'Hello World'**

if you want to instantiate an object of that class you need to do something like this:

```
name_of_object = CustomClass() # create an object

name_of_object.print_class() # this will call the method in that class
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `self` in a stand-alone function. If you define a class and instantiate it, `self` will refer to that object. You’re trying to use an attribute of a class object in the context of no object.

Example:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    def print_me(self):
        print(self.text)

o = Test(‘Hello world’)
o.print_me()
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Code:

```
class CustomClass:
    def print_class(self):
        print(self)

myClass = CustomClass()
myClass.print_class()
```